# Ubuntu 22.04 php8.1-fpm wifth Apache - 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: php, fastcgi, php-fpm

I installed php8.1-fpm on Ubuntu 22.04. In principle, I set everything up, but still "403 Forbidden
You do not have permission to access this resource "error message is displayed. The system is configured on an internal network with a self-signed certificate for development purposes.

I've done it with virtualmin so far, but now I want to get used to it ... I bought the configuration basics from there, but obviously something is still missing

*/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.dev.conf*:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.4:443>
    SuexecUserGroup "#1000" "#1000"

    ServerName "mydomain.dev"

    DocumentRoot "/home/mydomain/public_html"

    ErrorLog "/home/mydomain/etc/log/md_error_log"
    CustomLog "/home/mydomain/etc/log/md_access_log" "combined"

    ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "/home/mydomain/etc/cgi-bin/"

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    <Directory "/home/mydomain/public_html">
        Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php8.1
        FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain/etc/fcgi-bin/php8.1.fcgi .php
        FCGIWrapper /home/mydomain/etc/fcgi-bin/php8.1.fcgi .php8.1
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/mydomain/etc/cgi-bin">
        allow from all
        AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/mydomain/etc/certs/mydomain.dev+4.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/mydomain/etc/certs/mydomain.dev+4-key.pem
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/mydomain/.local/share/mkcert/rootCA.pem
    IPCCommTimeout 31
</VirtualHost>
```

*/home/mydomain/etc/fcgi-bin/php8.1.fcgi*:

```
#!bin/bash
PHPRC=$PWD/../etc/php8.1
export PHPRC
unmask 022
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=20
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=99999
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
exec /bin/php-cgi8.1
```

*/etc/mydomain/public_html* and subdirectories permissions: 0755
files permissions: 0644

error log (there is no link to */favicon.ico*):

```
[Mon Apr 25 14:22:06.490822 2022] [core:error] [pid 24678] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.0.4:51818] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/mydomain/public_html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Mon Apr 25 14:22:06.721894 2022] [core:error] [pid 24678] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.0.4:51818] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/mydomain/public_html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: https://mydomain.dev/
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: What are the file permissions for /home/mydomain/public_html ?

Comment: You are mixing Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4 syntax, which [leads to indeterminate results and is discouraged](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time). Use the proper syntax for your version.

Comment: Additionally: Your site config file is missing the VirtualHost definition. This could collide with other VirtualHosts. And is the site enabled  (meaning does a symlink to it in `sites-enabled` exist)?

Comment: /etc/mydomain/public_html/ and subdirectories
owner/group: mydomain
permissions: rwx r-x r-x
/etc/mydomain/public_html/*.php *.css etc
owner/group: mydomain
permissions: rw- r-- r--

Comment: yes: exists the sites-enabled

Comment: only this one VirtualHost exists outside the 00-default.conf and default-ssl.conf

Comment: this is behind the original question:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.dev.conf:
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.4:443> ... </VirtualHost>

Comment: you do not really host your web files in `/etc`? Moreover, administration Panel are off-topic for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Add the user to the www-data group:

```
usermod -g www-data username
```

Source: http://www.anoneh.com/208.php

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you